# extract value from column(contains xml) in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, extract

I'm trying to extract value from a column containing xml.

here's a snippet from my xml, where i want the value of "fieldscreen.id"

```
<action id="141" name="Abandonner" view="fieldscreen">
          <meta name="issue.editable">false</meta>
          <meta name="description">Abandonnée</meta>
          <meta name="fieldscreen.id">10102</meta>
          <restrict-to>
            <conditions>
              <condition type="class">
```

Please help me with the sql where i get only the value of fieldscreen.id from the column.
Database- mysql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySql query to retrieve value of element attribute of xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343016/mysql-query-to-retrieve-value-of-element-attribute-of-xml)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> set @xml:='<action id="141" name="Abandonner" view="fieldscreen">\n<meta name="issue.editable">false</meta>\n<meta name="description">Abandonnée</meta>\n<meta name="fieldscreen.id">10102</meta>\n</action>';
> ```

> ```
> SELECT ExtractValue(@xml, 'action/meta[@name="fieldscreen.id"]');
> ```
>
> ```
> | ExtractValue(@xml, 'action/meta[@name="fieldscreen.id"]') |
> | :-------------------------------------------------------- |
> | 10102                                                     |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=61ece3b72dd0f351ceb08e52df5436bd)*

Comment: Hi Akina, 
when i run the query for my column in database which has full xml, it gives null result.

Comment: @Ritika *when i run the query for my column in database which has full xml, it gives null result.* Edit my fiddle, insert 3-5 YOUR REAL record values instead of example value, and give new link - 'll look at...

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c4ebd602783b104b93f9d11cb951ea8

Comment: @Ritika 1) Always check for quote chars in string literals, and quote them (double, for example). 2) There is NO entity with the name "fieldscreen.id" in your XML - but there are 6 entities with the name "jira.fieldscreen.id" and more complex paths.